# unable to connect MYSQL docker container from spring boot app

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

I have MYSQL container Running i am able to execute it and able to connect from host machine using "mysql -h 172.17.0.2 -u root -p". I have executed "docker run --name=mysql-host -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:5.7.32" to run the docker image.

but when i trying to access through Spring boot app it`s giving connection refused below are the properties in the application.properties

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.2:3306/auditLog?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false
>
> spring.datasource.username=root
>
>  spring.datasource.password=root

i am runnung my jar as given below

> java -jar service-1.0.0.jar spring.config.location=file:///home/10662598/Downloads/entity-search-service-deploymentFolder/entity-search-service/configs/application.properties

> **Error getting Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)**

Comment: Where is your Spring boot app running? On host or inside mysql docker container or inside a separate docker container.

Comment: on my local machine, it is not dockerized. executing the above command to run that.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably because the Spring boot app can't reach the database (mysql), the reason for this is probably because they're not in same network.

### If your Spring boot app is running inside container

From your question, I see that you're running containers using `docker run...`, therefore when you start MySQL and Spring boot app using that command, they're not in same network.

Solution for this is, first create a network, then start MySQL and Spring app to run within that network:

```
docker network create my-net
```

Then start your containers as usual but remember to add your containers to the network you just created:

```
docker run ... --network my-net
```

Now your containers are in same network and should reach each other, you can verify this by exec to Spring boot app and try `curl` to Mysql container using its container name (and port):

```
curl <mysql_container_name>:3306
```

### If Spring boot app is running on host machine

Then simply make sure you map Mysql port to host machine and connect using `localhost:<mapped_port>`

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Here, you must create a network layer between the containers.

1. First create network layer

> docker network create spring-mysql-net

2. Build & Run MySql Docker image

> docker run --name mysql -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -v
> mysql:/var/lib/mysql --network spring-mysql-net mysql:8

3. Build your spring boot or any API

> docker build -t restapi .

4. Start container on that created the network

> docker container run --network spring-mysql-net --name
> mysql-restapi-container -p 8080:8080 -d restapi

Answer (score -2):

a bit late but i think you need to forward port 3306 on local machine to the contain port 3306
try this

docker run --name=mysql-host -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:5.7.32